# If $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=L$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^{1/k}=L^{1/k}$. {Edited]

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need some help proving the following statement:

[EDIT]: forgot to mention that:

$a_n \ge 0$ , $L \ge 0$.

If the limit of a sequence $\lim_{ \ n \to \infty} a_n=L$,
then, for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the limit of the sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{a_n}  = \sqrt[k]{L}$.

I already proved that every sequence $\{a_n\}^k$ converges to $L^k$ by induction step,
but when I tried the same for $\{1/k\}$, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Note that if $k=2$ and if $a_{n} < 0$ for some $n \geq 1$, then $a_{n}^{1/k}$ is meaningless.

Comment: forgot to mention that:

$a_n≥0 , L≥0$

Comment: What is the condition of k?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_{n} \geq 0$ for all $n \geq 1$, so that, if $a_{n} \to L$, then $L \geq 0$. This allows $a_{n}^{1/k}$ to be meaningful for all $n,k \geq 1$.

Let $k \geq 1$. If $L=0$, then the statement is obvious; for, we have $a_{n} < \varepsilon$ iff $a_{n}^{1/k} < \varepsilon^{1/k}$. Suppose $L > 0$. Then there is some $N_{1} \geq 1$ such that $a_{n} > 0$ for all $n \geq N_{1}$. If $n \geq N_{1}$, then
$$
|a_{n}^{1/k} - L^{1/k}| = \frac{|a_{n}-L|}{ \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a_{n}^{\frac{j}{k}}L^{\frac{k-1-j}{k}}}.
$$
On the other hand, there is some $N_{2} \geq N_{1}$ such that $n \geq N_{2}$ implies
$|a_{n} - L| < L/2$, implying $L/2 < a_{n}$, implying that
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} a_{n}^{\frac{j}{k}} L^{\frac{k-1-j}{k}} >  L^{\frac{k-1}{k}}/ \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{2^{\frac{j}{k}}} =: M.
$$
If $\varepsilon > 0$, then there is some $N_{3} \geq N_{2}$ such that $n \geq N_{3}$ implies $|a_{n}-L| < M\varepsilon$.
We have proved that, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $N \geq 1$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|a_{n}^{1/k} - L^{1/k}| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @YvesHalimi No problem; I hope you find it helpful in your case. :)

Comment: I don't understand why is the first equality is true?
 (after your first use of definiton of limit N1)

Comment: @YvesHalimi Note that $x^{k} - y^{k} = (x-y)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}x^{j}y^{k-1-j}$; apply this with $x := a_{n}^{1/k}$ and $y := L^{1/k}$.

Comment: And then $L/2<an$ makes it possible to write an inequality and change the $a_n$ with $L/2$ ? I just wanna make sure i understand correctly.
(My first year studying mathematics in the university.)

Comment: @YvesHalimi No worries. :) Yes, the purpose was to get rid of the denominator and obtain a further upper bound.

Comment: So after you denoted the right part of the inequality by M,
you're using the limit definition, and how exactly you conclude the last sentence? (i'm trying to write it down myself).

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use the fact that $f(x) = x^p$ is continuous together with the definition of limit (and continuity), it's straight forward just to chain these definitions.

The only thing that may remain is to prove that $f$ is continuous. This is done by providing an estimate of $f(x+h)-f(x)$, that is to become arbitrarily small for small enough $h$. We can use monotonicity of $f$ and that we can compute it's inverse. Just assume $\delta>0$ and consider $f^{-1}(f(x)\pm\delta) = (x^p\pm\delta)^{1/p}$, this gives us an interval such that $|f(x+h)-f(x)|<\delta$.

To be concrete assume that $k$ is a positive integer, and that $\lim a_n=L$. Consider a $\delta > 0$, now consider any $x$ such that $(L^{1/k}-\delta)^k <x<(L^{1/k}+\delta)^k$, then we will have $L^{1/k}-\delta<x^{1/k}<L^{1/k}+\delta$. Now since $\lim a_n = L$ and that $(L^{1/k} - \delta)^k < (L^{1/k})^k = L < (L^{1/k}+\delta)^k$ we have a $N$ such that $|a_n - L|$ is less than both $L - (L^{1/k}-\delta)^k$ and $(L^{1/k}+\delta)^k-L$ and there fore $(L^{1/k}-\delta)^k < a_n < (L^{1/k}+\delta)^k$ for all $n>N$, therefore we have $L^{1/k}-\delta<a_n^{1/k}<L^{1/k}+\delta$ (which shows that $\lim a_n^{1/k} = L^{1/k}$). Note though that we must take special care if $L^{1/k}-\delta<0$, for $L>0$ this means only to restrict $\delta$ so this can't happen, but in general we would use the fact that $a_n>0$ instead for the lower bound in the inequalities.